Insert multiple non-copyable values to `std::vector`
Inserting N values to an std::vector one-by-one is inefficient.
So, you can insert them all-at-once.
My problem is that my values are not copy-constructible.
So, the question is how can I make the following code to work without inserting one-by-one the values.
Is there a mapping process which takes one std::string and one DOMObject* and give a Field? Is there a move semantics feeding to std::vector?
#include <span>
#include <concepts>
#include <iterator>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;


class DOMObject {};


struct Field
{
    std::string key;
    std::unique_ptr<DOMObject> value;
};


std::vector<Field> fields;


void insert_many(size_t pos, const std::span<string> &keys, const std::span<DOMObject*> &values)
{
    fields.insert(fields.begin() + pos, values.size(), {});  // Copy construction is not allowed
    for (size_t i = 0; i < values.size(); ++i)
    {
        fields[pos + i].key = std::move(keys[i]);
        fields[pos + i].value.reset(values[i]);
    }
}


int main()
{
}


"So, you can insert them all-at-once." - what do you mean by "all-at-once" ? In any case some kind of an iteration is needed (whether in your code, or in the library code).

All-at-once I mean the existed elements in fields after pos moved forward for values.size() places and not for one place values.size() times.

insert_range is c++23 ... so you need to write your own, you need to resize the vector, then move the elements to the end, then move the other elements to the middle.

Like this : combination of insert and make_move_iterator
#include <string>
#include <memory>
#include <span>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

class DOMObject 
{
};

struct Field
{
    Field() { std::cout << "Field()\n"; }
    Field(const Field&) = delete;
    Field& operator=(const Field&) = delete;
    Field(Field&&) noexcept { std::cout << "Field(Field&&)\n"; }
    Field& operator=(Field&&) noexcept { std::cout << "Field =Field&&\n"; return *this; }
    ~Field() { std::cout << "~Field()\n"; }

    std::string key;
    std::unique_ptr<DOMObject> value;
};

void insert_many(std::vector<Field>& fields, std::span<Field> new_fields)
{
    std::cout << "inserting\n";
    fields.insert(fields.end(), std::make_move_iterator(new_fields.begin()), std::make_move_iterator(new_fields.end()));
}

int main()
{
    {
    std::vector<Field> fields(3);
    std::vector<Field> new_fields(2);

    fields[0].key = "one";
    fields[1].key = "two";
    fields[2].key = "three";
    new_fields[0].key = "four";
    new_fields[1].key = "five";
    
    insert_many(fields,new_fields);
    for(auto& value : fields)
    {
        std::cout << value.key << "\n";
    }
    } //extra scope for deletion of vectors
}


It's easy if you already have them bundled up in a range of Field rather than in two separate ranges like in OP's original code.

I didn't play with ranges but it seems that they have the solution:
    std::transform(keys.begin(), keys.end(), values.begin(),
                std::inserter(fields, fields.begin() + pos),
                [](std::string &key, DOMObjectType *value) -> Field
                        { return {std::move(key), unique_pointer{value}}; });

